# How can i show the following error message using javascript

Tags: visualforce

```
 integer EmailCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Email =:le.Email AND Id !=:le.Id];
                        if (EmailCount > 0)
                      {
                          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Email id already exists'));
                      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any Javascript.

Just add the following tag to your Visualforce page: `<apex:messages />`

Comment: my requirement is javascript alert message

Comment: @RaghavendraReddy Populate email count when page is loaded or any event which suits your requirement and store it in Javascript variable. write `actionFunction` and invoke javascript function. Check email count stored in Javascript function and give alert.

Comment: can you explain detailly

Comment: @RaghavendraReddy posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You will introduce the JavaScript on the client side (Visualforce). In order to do this you need an apex property to run the validation on before you can call the `alert()`. This example is using a button to check the email count, you may need it done at load time so the controller may need to change on your end. But its a start....

**Apex:**

```
    public Integer emailCount {get;set;}

    // Fired when the countEmail button is clicked
    public PageReference countEmail() {
        String qry = 'SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Email =:le.Email AND Id !=:le.Id';
        this.emailCount = Database.query(qry);
        return null;
    }
```

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page controller="...">
  <script>
    function validateEmailCount(){
        if('{!emailCount.size}' == 0){
            alert('No Emails found.');
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:panelGroup >
        <apex:commandButton value="Check Email Count" onComplete="validateEmailCount();"
              action="{!countEmail}" rerender="block"/>

.......
```

Answer (score 0):

> Include   `<apex:messages />` in visual force Page

[reference Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_message.htm)

Comment: my requirement is javascript alert message

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detail answer to put validation using Javascript

**Apex Class**:

```
// constructor
public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    // initialize it by querying the database
    emailCount = 1;
}

public Integer emailCount {get;set;}

public void apexMethod(){
    // do further processing if record is validated properly
}
```

**VF Code:**

```
<script>    

    function validateCount() {
        var count = {!emailCount};
        console.log('count::'+count);
        if(count > 0) {
            alert('Email id already exists');
            return false;
        } else {
             // else call apex method
             invokeController ();                
        }
    }
</script>


<apex:commandButton value="Validate Count" onclick="validateCount(); return false;"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="invokeController" action="{!apexMethod}" reRender="dummy"/>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Not throwing a alert,record is inserting